# Cant make a crossdomain Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, youtube-api

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zdf/playlists?v=2",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    });

i get this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zdf/playlists?v=2"

How can i make crossdomain ajax calls to get the xml from the api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot make a crossdomain call to to get XML. Your only choice to receive data crossdomain is `JSON-P`.

The `same origin policy` restricts direct access to a foreign domain (ajax/iframes), `json-p` uses `dynamic script tag insertion` to workaround this issue.

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. `JSON-P` is also covered there.

**edit**

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json.html

Made for you!

Comment: you need at least a deze core cpu!

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing standardization process to work out a scheme to allow cross-domain ajax requests JSON-P is just a temporary workaround since it uses the script tag to make HTTP requests, which is inferior to the XMLHttpRequest object.

The proposed solution is based on letting the resource origin specify which domains that are allowed to make cross-domain requests, the domain "*" means that any other web page can host an application that makes requests to that specific resource.

You can read more in the w3c Working [draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/)

This is supported in modern web-browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try $.load() . see http://api.jquery.com/load/